# PN532 NFC credit card/debit card emulation

Tags: nfc, microcontroller, hce

I am working on a project where i want to emulate Credit/Debit card using pn532 NFC module.
I tried to find out the protocol to in which i can send the credit/debit information to the Credit/debit card reader. I tried to search about this but didn't get proper document.
I need help on this.

1. What all information should i send to reader?
2. Exchange protocol in Credit card emulation mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find an explanation of how to put a PN532 into card emulation mode in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051315/nfc-acr122-tginitastarget-initiator-releasing-target/21107403#21107403).
2. The protocols for (contactless) credit cards are specified by EMVCo. You can find their specifications on their [website](http://www.emvco.com/).