# Step by Step, How to send a URL through card emulation with the ACR122U to phones?

Tags: windows, nfc

I am trying to emulate a ACR122U to pass a url to my phone (ex - youtue.com or instagram.com). It should work with iphones and androids alike. I have so far attempted on using libraries (nfcpy, pyscard) to do this but seem to not get far. I have heard about libnfc and at this point, I am willing to do anything for this to work.

I have searched all over stackoverflow for answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854933/how-to-card-emulate-with-acr122u-a9), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726444/acr122u-card-emulation-mode-send-pn532-commands), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096356/transfer-data-to-pc-from-android-device-via-nfc?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661808/acr122-card-emulation) and I even have reached to people on upwork/fiverr but they seem to not know how.

I believe card emulation with the ACS ACR122U is a bit tricky to set up (as ive been trying to do this for days). Please if you know how, can you list a detailed step by step setup for card emulation with this reader. I know other posts have had bits and pieces but for a rookie, this can be very confusing just to see bits of a solution everywhere. Please do not tell me to read the PN532 guide or the ACS manual as i have went through both of those and I am still quite lost. I have a million questions on this matter and I would rather just get a step by step guide to save everyone time. I am on windows and I am willing to use any library to do this. Also, when it comes to the APDU commands, I am not that familiar so if you are going to have a solution using this then please explain what i need to have to run these commands and how i can run these commands and where can i run them. There are posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854933/how-to-card-emulate-with-acr122u-a9) that are great however are missing context on where/how to run these commands. So please be as detailed as possible on the steps and how exactly to follow them.

Thank You

Comment: This is a big question and needs a bit more focus. Some general pointers:- A lot of the questions you referenced are about sending/receiving an array of bytes to the ACR122. The bytes configure the ACR122 in to the right mode for card emulation and then the ACR122 passes array of bytes for each APDU's for your program to decode and then formulate a response that you need to send back to the ACR122 for it to then send on to the NFC Tag. So in general you will need to write a program to send these array of bytes "Commands" to the ACR122

Comment: After i send these byte commands, how will i be able to send my url message (like an ndef)? Can i even send ndef messages?

Comment: You would need to respond to the APDU's in the correct way to look like a Ndef Type 4 Tag that contains a Ndef message that contains the URL. The spec of how to do that is at https://web.archive.org/web/20210415042735/https://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf . As an example https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid is an implementation of card emulation on Android (this shows which APDU's you need to respond to, but how they are sent to the hardware is totally different)